# Definitive measurement of the correct "gravity potential difference" and uncertainty of its determination by "conventional measurement"

Tags: experimental-physics, potential, metrology

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04089) ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41567-017-0042-3)) describing recent experiments on "*Geodesy and metrology with a transportable clock*" featuring a "*transportable Sr optical lattice clock*" there is an interesting remark towards the end (p. 11):

> *The chronometric levelling can be viewed from  an alternative perspective: If we assume the conventional measurement of the gravity potential difference is correct then we can deduce an average absolute frequency value of 429 288 004 229 873.13(40) Hz for the Sr lattice clock.*

This raises several related questions:

1. If the "*conventional measurement [procedure]* for determining gravity potential difference" does not obtain correct results **by definition** (but the correctness of thereby obtained values may merely be assumed) then **what exactly is the definitive measurement procedure** by which gravity potential difference would be determined correctly ?
2. If knowledge of correct values of the gravity potential difference is a prerequisite for deducing an (average absolute) frequency value of a clock under consideration, especially in comparison between different trials (from which average values might be determined) and/or in comparison to some "realization of $1~{\rm Hz}$", then **should the corresponding uncertainty be evaluated** and explicitly listed e.g. in the "*Typical uncertainty budgets of the optical clocks*" (Tab. 1, p.3) ?
3. Does the "*Comparison of absolute frequency measurements of the Sr clock transition*" (Fig. Supp1, p. 11) account for uncertainties in the determination of values of the gravity potential difference by "*conventional measurement [procedure]*" wrt. the corresponding correct values ?

Comment: It's metrology. Considering the option of changing the definition, and  weighing up the consequences is part of what they do.

Comment: @dmckee: "_It's metrology._" -- I agree. And as such it's also experimental physics. These tags had been applied already. (Btw., I also tried to apply explicitly the available `tag:graviational-potential` since that's the topic. Unfortunately/inexplicably that's converted to the somewhat less specific `tag:potential`.) "_Considering the option of changing the definition, and weighing up the consequences is part of what they do._" -- Surely it's always about **specific, comprehensible/reproducible/communicable** definitions. My question: **Which one** did Grotti et al. suppose specificly?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost like you were intentionally trying to misread the whole paper. The whole point of the piece is using independently calibrated clocks to do geodesy ("chronometric levelling"). In that spirit, they use standard optical time metrology to calibrate and characterize the optical clocks, and they use those calibrated clocks to measure their relative frequency difference, which provides an optical measurement of the gravitational potential difference $\Delta U$ between the two clocks, which can then be compared against standard techniques.

That is, they measure $\Delta U$ using completely optical techniques and then, as an anchor, they compare the results of this optical chronometric levelling with alternative, classical methods, i.e.

> The potential difference between LSM and INRIM was **also** determined independently by a combination of GNSS (global navigation satellite system), spirit levelling and gravimetric geoid modelling (see Methods).

(emphasis added) which is what your quote calls "the conventional measurement of the gravity potential difference", also called "geodetic means" elsewhere in the paper, and which are described at length in the 'Gravity potential determination' subsection under Methods.

Now, it should be granted that their presentation of their results is a little obscure. The core part of their results is Fig. 1b:

> [image]
>
> **b** Frequency of the transportable Sr clock as seen by the INRIM Cs fountain clock (black circles, uncertainties are one standard deviation of the combined uncertainties). The potential difference $ΔU$ is based on the geodetic measurement. The red line shows the expected variation of the Sr clock transition frequency due to the relativistic redshift.

This means that what they are really presenting is (i) an optical measurement of $\Delta \nu$ on the horizontal axis, plotted against (ii) the conventional measurement of $\Delta U$ on the vertical axis. The red line shows the optical $\Delta U = c^2 \Delta\nu/\nu_0$, i.e. if you want to get the optical measurement of $\Delta U$, you just take the position of the red line at the experimentally measured $\Delta \nu$.

This is precisely what they then go on to do in the main text: they infer the value of $\Delta U$ from the optical measurements, and they compare it to the geodetic one:

> In this chronometric levelling demonstration, we resolved a relativistic redshift of the optical lattice clock of $47.92(83)\:\rm Hz$ (Fig. 1), from which we infer a potential difference of $10,034(174) \rm \: m^2 \:s^{-2}$ [..]. This is in excellent agreement with the value of $10,032.1(16) \: \rm m^2 \: s^{-2}$ determined independently by geodetic means.

The main takeaways here are that (i) the measurements agree within their (independent!) experimental uncertainties, and (ii) the optical measurements are not as precise as the standard geodetic approach. That is, the optical uncertainty in $\Delta U$ is $174 \rm \: m^2 \:s^{-2}$, whereas the geodetic methods pin it down to $1.6 \: \rm m^2 \: s^{-2}$, i.e. about a factor of $100$ smaller.

(For scale, the geodetic uncertainty boils down to some $16\:\rm cm$ in height, consistent with the decimeter-level uncertainties quoted earlier in the paper, while the chronometric levelling is accurate to about $18\:\rm m$. Not bad, but not precision surveying either. Also, the Methods section makes it pretty clear they didn't try *that* hard on the traditional geodesy ─ they had it down to a $6\:\rm cm$ uncertainty at the level of the reference markers near the clocks, and then lost an additional $10\:\rm cm$ of precision when referencing to the clocks, presumably because it wasn't necessary to be more precise than they already were.)

This means that, as yet, it does not make sense to replace geodetic measurements with chronometric levelling, which is not as precise. This is pretty acceptable given that the paper you've cited is the very first demonstration of the optical procedure.

If, at some point, the uncertainty in $\Delta U$ from optical chronometric levelling increases to the point where it is significantly better than traditional geodetic measurement, then it may well take the place of the "definitive" method to do that measurement. (Whatever that term "definitive" means - $\Delta U$ is not encoded as a definition in the SI, and metrologists are free to use whatever method gets the most precise results.

---

Now: **The part you quote is explicitly labeled as an alternative perspective** (and in an out-of-the-way addendum in a supplement, no less), i.e. what would happen if you turned the whole thing around on its head and used independent geodesy to interpret the results as a calibration for the optical clock.

As such, this brings in the geodetic measurement into the optical error budget **exclusively** for the purposes of the inferred value for $\Delta\nu_\mathrm{Sr}$ reported in the passage you quote. The value thus obtained is consistent with other optical measurements, which is precisely what you'd expect given the existing agreement in the main text's optical and geodetic measurements of $\Delta U$.

Thus, to be explicit: **No**, the geodetic uncertainties should *not* be included in the error budgets for optical clocks, unless one were to change the procedure and use the measurements of $\Delta \nu/\nu_0$ over a geodetically-calibrated height difference as your clock procedure. I have no idea why anyone would think that's a good idea (among other reasons, because the error budgets would have more things in them), but if you were to try that then yes, you'd need to have more things in your error budgets.

Similarly, as regards the supplementary figure: the bulk of the measurements that figure reports (all the points except the one marked LSM 16) were measured in single optical laboratories and were not measured by comparing two independent clocks at a geodetically-determined height difference, so geodetic uncertainties do not play a role.

The LSM 16 point *does* use this procedure (as proposed in the section it's in, explicitly marked as an alternative perspective), and as such, the uncertainties in the geodetic measurement **do** need to be included in the error budget. This is not reported explicitly (which is natural for an off-to-the-side alternative perspective that's not mentioned in the main text) but it is safe to assume that it has been done.

However, it's important to note that the LSM 16 point comes from that truck in the tunnel ─ the one where the thermal fluctuations and mechanical vibrations degraded the clock performance. Since the corresponding uncertainty in the optical measurement in $\Delta U$ was about a hundred times bigger than the geodetic measurement, the contribution of the geodetic uncertainty to the error budget of $\nu_\mathrm{Sr, LSM16}$ will be of the order of 1% (again, not explicitly reported as it's not the main result, but accounted for correctly barring any scientific misconduct).

Comment: I should say this: I'm providing this answer against my better judgement, given your extensive record of launching into rants and other extended discussions. I am not at all interested in such a discussion ─ the answer is presented as is, and you can take it or leave it in its current form. I may, or may not, answer questions, but I reserve the right to cut the conversation short at any point. (This is particularly the case for comments that abuse formatting emphasis as you've done in the question and the comments under it ─ if you want me to respond, do not use any markdown emphasis.)

Comment: Emilio Pisanty: "_It's almost like you were intentionally trying to misread the whole paper. The whole point of the piece is using independently calibrated clocks to do geodesy_" -- It's certainly my intention to question what might be meant by calling clocks "_calibrated_" if their geometric relations were not known; or in other words, if "the geodesy had not been done", trial by trial, by suitable definitive means, without requiring or presuming "_calibrated clocks_". Moreover, I reserve pointing out further questionable aspects of your answer for readers to come. p.s. +1 for effort.